# Python Mongodb aggregation with Jinja2

Tags: python, mongodb, jinja2

I'm using Python to query mongo to get the overall counts of values:

```
pipeline = [
    {"$unwind": '$account_details'},
    {"$group": {"_id": {"platform": "$account_details.platform"}, 
"count": {"$sum": 1}}}
]
cursor = coll.aggregate(pipeline)
result = list(cursor)
```

The result is as follows:

```
[{u'count': 5, u'_id': {u'platform': u'windows'}}, {u'count': 926, 
u'_id': {u'platform': u'Linux'}}]
```

I'm using Jinja2 templating to display the result, how can I display these values separately

what I tried is e.g

```
{{ result.windows.count }}
```

Comment: It's a list. You need to iterate a list, or just slice the 1st element if you expect only one result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the template use a `for` loop to iterate the items in the list, then you can access values within them by keys using the dot notation. For example, to get...

- windows: 5
- Linux: 926

...you can write

```
<ul>
 {% for item in result %}
  <li>{{ item._id.platform }}: {{ item.count }}</li>
 {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

You can adapt this to get a table or anything else.

Comment: Thank you rrobby86, this is great, is there any way to split it to show the results individually?

Comment: Sorry, sorted it now, just wrapped my whole element in the loop to split it.